# How do I best help the reader understand the contextual meaning meaning of a particular phrase?

Tags: essay, text-analysis

In *The Things They Carried*, the soldiers “carried all the emotional baggage of men who might die. Grief, terror, love, longing - these were intangibles, but the intangibles had their own mass and specific gravity, their own weight.” (57)

What I'd like to do is explain what the author meant when he said "the intangibles had their own...specific gravity". I was thinking I could start by explaining the physical concept of "specific gravity". Specific gravity, put simply, is the ratio of one object's density to that of another. If I put an object in water and that object's specific gravity, relative to the water, is greater than 1, the object might sink.  So, maybe O'Brien is saying these intangibles are sinking.

Comment: Why do you want to explain it? Is it for a study guide?

Comment: I don't think the author is referring to the scientific concept of specific gravity in this case.  Instead, I believe that 'specific', in this context should be interpreted independent of the word gravity, with a meaning closer to 'distinct' or 'unique'.  What I think the author is trying to convey is that a warrior's emotions weigh upon them, very much like the weight of the weapons and armour which they carry, but distinct in their particular nature, because emotions cannot be put down while the warrior rests.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are attempting to describe metaphor literally.

Consider -

```
All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players;
They have their exits and their entrances[...]
—William Shakespeare, As You Like It
```

Shakespeare is not trying to say that the world is actually a stage, but that it bears some resemblance to one, he then goes on embellish the description

It seems you are attempting to describe the colour of the curtains, the size and shape of the men and women, and the location of the exits and entrances. (which could be appropriate if your audience are stage builders)

If you want to explain what the author meant, you should be concentrating on why (s)he is making that comparison, what essence does a stage have that makes it comparable to a world

What essence does Grief, terror, love, longing have to give them a property comparable to a weight to be carried.